# Index numbers and average prices

Tags: self-study, econometrics

My dad was saying the following: suppose that over the last year, a certain product, let's say milk, has doubled in price, while another product, say bread, has dropped to half the price. Someone now claims that prices has gone up" and uses the following argument: if we put prices on 100 last year, then the price of milk now is 200, and the price of bread is down to 50. On average this means the price is 125, compared to 100 last year. However I am not entirely convinced this is right. Can somebody:

1. Give an argument that shows (in the exact same circumstances) that
   the average price did not go up, but instead went actually down in the same
   period. (Is there a reason to set last year's prices to 100?)
2. Is there a name for this phenomenon? How does it exactly work.

Comment: How much milk do you drink with your bread?

Answer (score 6):

As I believe @whuber is alluding to (+1), it's very important to consider how prices are weighted and combined.  Generally, [inflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation) reflects the weighted average price of a basket of goods.  But, those weights should reflect amounts that are being purchased.  See [Consumer price index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Price_Index).

Note that if, in your example, people buy equal amounts of milk and bread at the original prices (100 each), and, after the price changes, people buy the same amount of bread, but half the amount of milk, the weighted average price stays the same: $(200*.5+50*1)/1.5=100$.  If people buy double the amount of bread, and half the amount of milk, the weighted average price goes down: $(200*.5+50*2)/2.5=80$.